# Rails verifiying the presence of a class with assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following markup in my rails app:

```
<body class="hello">
```

I'm trying to use **assert_select** to verify that the body tag has a class of **hello**

```
assert_select "body.hello"
```

But my test keeps failing with the following output:

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "body.hello", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

I've tried the following:

```
assert_select "body[class=hello]"
```

But I get the same message.

I know that **assert_select** works because the following passes just fine `assert_select "body"`

FWIW, this is happening in a controller test. Many of the rails docs seem to indicate that you can use assert_select in the way I'm trying to. I don't understand this. Has this method changed recently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, and I've used that `assert_select "body.class_name"` many times myself in controller tests. I would guess that the `<body>` tag is not what you think it is in this test, to see what it is just add a `puts` in to get the full chunk of HTML output, ie.:

```
puts assert_select 'body'
```

This will show you what the body tag is in your test and perhaps you'll see the problem.